# How to turn off brower's pop-up when an EvenListener is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a function to save a property called PageSize before a page is reloaded.
For now, It did update the value but everytime I clicked on the refresh button or close button of the browser, a pop-up appear like this:

```
This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.
Stay on Page       Leave Page
```

Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Event is called here
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onUnload);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onUnload);
  };
},[]);

const onUnload = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var pageSize = parseInt(document.querySelector("input").value);
  if (thisTable) {
    // The line below help saving property
    saveTablePreference("pageSize", pageSize, "ComWorkUnitsView"); 
  }
  event.returnValue="";
}
```

If I delete the line `event.preventDefault();`, the Pop-up won't appear but nothing will be saved.

Is there anyway to solve this problem ?

Comment: What does `saveTablePreference` do?

Comment: @idmean, It helps saving "pageSize" to my database

Comment: Yes, but how does it do that? Asynchronous HTTP request?

Comment: It is Asynchronous HTTP Request

Comment: This is very much the problem. If you don't call `preventDefault` the browser will unload your page, and that will probably mean that the browser immediately cancels your request.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227683/discussion-between-luong-minh-tam-and-idmean).

Comment: You cannot. It's the users decision if they want to stay on your site or not. You cannot force them.